# Keyword Automatic Clicker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, applescript

I would like a JavaScript code that will allow me to specify a certain keyword and have Twitter click on a link that contains that keyword. The script should be made for Google Chrome and has to work with the internet Twitter source, TweetDeck. I have tried this but to no avail.

```
set myKeyword to "Jordan"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set URL to "https://web.tweetdeck.com/"
        delay 3
        set num_links to (execute javascript "document.links.length") - 1
        repeat with i from 0 to num_links
            set myLink to execute javascript "document.links[" & i & "].href"
            if myLink contains myKeyword then
                execute javascript "document.links[" & i & "].click()"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using javascript? That doesn't look like any programming language that I recognize.

Comment: @Michael0x2a It's a mixture of [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) and JavaScript

Comment: That's what I thought because I have usually seen functions displayed to start off the coding. Is there anyway you could give suggestions as to what to fix? It would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!